# Blazor WASM confirm password or re-login

Tags: azure-ad-msal, blazor-webassembly

I'm creating an application in Blazor WebAssembly with `Microsoft.Authentication.WebAssembly.Msal` for the authentication. I followed this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-5.0). I'm using the `RemoteAuthenticatorView` component to perform a login. But I want that the user has to confirm his password for a critical operation. Or maybe he has to re-login. How can I do that ?

Edit: Previously, I used `Microsoft.Identity.Client` in a desktop application. To do the confirmation, I used the `AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword` function. But it's not possible in a webapp.

Comment: Do you want that the user for, in example, delete something redo the login process?

Comment: I want that he has to confirm his password with a <TextField /> for example to do any critical operation. Or if it's not possible, maybe a new login popup to confirm his identity.

Answer (score 0):

If you using the Azure AD Signin user flow a textfield for password input isn't possible.
This because the form containing the *field* has to be **Remote** inside the Azure AD domain.

If you want, as you propose as alternative, a popup to confirm the identity of the user, the only possibility is to logout the user and redirect him to the login.
But in this case you (he) lost any session data and it's hard to use the returnUrl parameter to restore the same status, with i.e. a form with data.

I think should be better to send an email with a verification code, or, as Microsoft does on the Azure Portal, request a *keyword* to confirm the operation.
Generally speaking this *keyword* could be any of your choice, in the past I've used a *secret* word configured by the user himself inside his profile page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think an email with a verification code is a good alternative.